# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

Tags: python, django

I created a Django project inside of `api` folder called `bucks`:

```
api
|____ categories/
    |____ __init__.py
    |____ ...
    |____ models.py
    |____ tests.py
    |____ views.py
|____ .../
|____ bucks/
|____ users/
    |____ __init__.py
    |____ ...
    |____ models.py
    |____ signals.py
    |____ tests.py
    |____ views.py
|____ __init__.py
|____ manage.py
webroot
|___ ...
```

And in my `bucks` folder inside the `api`, I am doing the following:

```
from api.users.views import CustomObtainAuthToken
```

But I am facing an error when I run `makemigrations`:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

I also tried to add `users.app.UsersConfig` in my `INTALLED_APPS`, but then, this error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

So I am in this impass. I couldn't find another way to import `CustomObtainAuthToken`, it'd only allow me to access it through that syntax.

Comment: Can you show more of your structure? Where are your settings and models?

Comment: Can't you do `from users.views import ...` rather than `from app.users.views ...`

Comment: Not sure why you expect this to work. There's no `users` below `api` and on top of that, `api` is not in the python path. `api` is the container, all imports should be relative to that. So from your structure as displayed, you can import `bucks` and `manage`, but not `webroot`.

Comment: have you added `api` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` IN `django settings`?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid, the question has been updated with a more detailed structure of my folders.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, yes I have.

Comment: @Melvyn, yes, `api` is just just a folder which has the django project inside. Perhaps I should move everything out of it?

Comment: @SachinKukreja, I cannot. It does not show my `users` application at all. I am using PyCharm, so if it were right it should list it as I start typing.

Comment: @SachinKukreja, I take it back. The IDE showing it's an error to import it like this is actually wrong, because I tried now and it worked, even if it accuses to have an error.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 Cool. You wont have any problems then.

Comment: @SachinKukreja, I do not. Sorry and thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

check your settings file if the name of the app is correct or not

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html)...

> If you need to have test modules with the same name, you might add **init**.py files to your tests folder and subfolders, changing them to packages

So you just need to add an empty `__init__.py` in all your tests folders and it will be it.