# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routers'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi

I've got this error :
from routers.patients import router as  PatientsRouter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routers'

When i try to run docker-compose up api with my project.

My file structure:

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /project

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./api /project/api/

CMD ["uvicorn", "api.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    command: ["uvicorn", "api.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
    volumes:
      - ./api:/project/api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: Your project Python paths begin with `api`; for example, you tell uvicorn that the main module is `api.main`.  In your code you need to `import api.routers` and so on.  (I'd expect you'd see the same problem in a non-Docker Python virtual environment, and that setup might be easier to debug.)

Comment: I'he tried this, but gave's me another error. When i run ```docker-compose pytest api```.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73242525/get-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-api?noredirect=1#comment129351708_73242525

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to import from routers, python needs the `__init__.py` file in that same directory to treat it as a module.

It looks like your `init` file in the api directory has an extra underscore at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue, and creating `__init__.py` file **did not** work (also, Python3 doesn't require them anyway). However, changing the WORKDIR to the main.py directory *(`/project/api` in your case)* and reflecting this change in the CMD array *(`main:app` instead of `api.main:app`)* fixed it for me.